# Screensaver on Windows login screen won't run on vista / 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-vista, screensaver

I've written a Screensaver in C# which uses ActiveX controls to display video and flash and we'd like to have run even when no user is logged on the machine it's installed on. The problem is threefold (so far). Part of the logic is to get the machine's physical memory at startup, by querying Win32_ComputerSystem. This works fine when you're logged on, no when you're logged off. Also, the app creates temp classes on Windows\system32 and that gives you an UnauthorizedAccessException when you do it when logged off. Finally, it seems that on Vista/7, the media codecs and Flash aren't loaded up until a user logs on, so the app would throw a runtime error when loading up from the login screen.

So basically my question is, how can the screensaver application gain access to the Windows\System32\|Syswow64 folders as well as the various WMI classes when no one is logged in? Obviously, for security reasons these are restricted but we plan to deploy the screensaver on a specific network so we can modify group policies etc on all the machines this screensaver will be running on. Also, media codecs are clearly unloaded on the Vista/7 login screen, so is there a way to enable those?

Comment: I think you are over complicating this process, does your screensaver run as an exe or a .scr? It could be you just have not installed it properly.

Comment: It's an SCR and is on Windoww\System32